# Where can I find the Asp.net MVC 3 SportsStore database download

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am starting this tutorial and would like to know if the complete database is anywhere to be found please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the zip of the sources there is a directory called `DatabaseScripts` you simply have to execute the script to create your Database

Comment: I have the book here so do not even know where to find the online zip file.. the book is: apress pro asp.net mvc2 framework :)

Comment: [http://sportsstoremvc3.codeplex.com/](A guy who followed the book). And from the [https://www.apress.com/9781430228868](Apress's site) there is the `source code` link. (That should be stated also in the first pages of the book if I remember correctly)